# How to get explained variance per PCA component in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, pca, apache-spark-ml

As far as I know, pyspark offers PCA API like:

```python
from pyspark.ml.feature import PCA
pca = PCA(k=3, inputCol="features", outputCol="pcaFeatures")
model = pca.fit(data_frame)
```

However in reality, I find explained variances ratio is more widely used. For example, in sklearn:

```python
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca_fitter = PCA(n_components=0.85)
```

Does anyone know how to implement explained variance ratio in pyspark? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Spark 2.0 onwards, `PCAModel` includes an `explainedVariance` method; from the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.PCAModel.explainedVariance):

> **`explainedVariance`**
>
> Returns a vector of proportions of variance explained by each principal component.
>
> *New in version 2.0.0.*

Here is an example with `k=2` principal components and toy data, adapted from the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.PCA):

```python
spark.version
# u'2.2.0'

from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.feature import PCA

data = [(Vectors.sparse(5, [(1, 1.0), (3, 7.0)]),),
...     (Vectors.dense([2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]),),
...     (Vectors.dense([4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0]),)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,["features"])
pca = PCA(k=2, inputCol="features", outputCol="pca_features")
model = pca.fit(df)

model.explainedVariance
# DenseVector([0.7944, 0.2056])
```

i.e. from our `k=2` principal components, the first one explains 79.44% of the variance, while the second one explains the remaining 20.56%.